# Script is generating Sequences under another schema

Tags: liquibase

When I am running my script It is generating my sequences under public schema of DB2 instead of my schema which I have mentioned in my java classes

Below are images:
[public schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfd0.png)
[desired schema - Hibernate Java Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyuEB.png)

if you need for any more info let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at --defaultSchemaName Liquibase parameter or if you are using sql statements you may specify schema explicitly in sql queries.

Comment: I couldn't find any "defaultSchemaName" parameter under annotation ***@SequenceGenerator***, ***@GeneratedValue***

Comment: @muhammadawais you need to pass this parameter to liquibase